# Best Practice for Manipulating UI Elements In Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, xcode4.2

I'll start by saying that I'm new to cocoa development.  I'm also surprised I didn't find a post about this already, but I've filtered through a number of posts now without success.

I have a set of elements that should change state based on the state of a long running algorithm.

Basically, I have a start button, a cancel button, and a next button.  The initial state of the app would be start button enabled, cancel and next buttons disabled.  The status of the algorithm should swap enabled / disabled on all the buttons as it progresses.

Every option for manipulating button state I have seen involves coding button.enabled into the controller code.  I'm coming from an ASP .NET MVC background as I dive into Cocoa and this seems backwards to me.  Shouldn't the view logic be separated from the controller logic in the MVC pattern?

To me, it seems I should be able to emit a couple boolean values as IBOutlets like algorithm running and algorithm success, and bind the button state at the view layer.  Do I need to toss this idea?  Or am I possibly missing something about the Cocoa version of design pattern (like the object I bind the view to should really be a view model, which interacts with a controller class)?  Or, lastly, is there an easy way to accomplish what I'm talking about, and I've just missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to code the enabled state of the button into your controller. What you can do is declare a `BOOL` property on your controller such as `isBusy` and then set this property to `YES` when you start your long operation and to `NO` when it's finished. You must do this using [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html)-compliant methods, which essentially means using the setter, so you'd call `self.isBusy = YES;`, for instance.

The reason you do this is because you can then use [Cocoa Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html) to set up a binding on the UI controls. Go into the bindings inspector for one of your buttons, and bind the `Enabled` binding to your controller object with a key path of `isBusy`.

Cocoa bindings uses [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) (KVO) to monitor the value of observed properties. When a change occurs in the `isBusy` property, the buttons that are bound to it will notice and change their `enabled` state in response.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I just completely missed the binding tab in Interface Builder.  I was surprised that I couldn't find a way to do it, but it was sitting right there in front of me.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the delegate model of Objective-C. In the example you are giving you could have your controller object running the algorithm and updating its status to its delegate, in this case the view.

i.e your `ViewController` object will call the `doSomething` method from the `ProgramController`; and when its over `ProgramController` will invoque the `somethingDidFinish` method from its delegate, as defined in your `ProgramControllerDelegate` protocol)

Comment: I'm reading about the delgate concept a bit more.  Thanks for pointing me to that.  At first glance, it sounds a bit like the view model paradigm I'm used to in .NET.  Essentially, I need one more controller class than I have.  Does that sound right?  I'm extending a legacy app that maybe blends too many layers into one controller object, and I blindly followed that example.

Comment: I'm not sure about your particular need, but for the example above two classes suffice, one for the view and one for the controller, in which the view implements the delegation protocol of the controller so the controller can 'inform' the view about the progress.